# Core Data MagicalRecord: fetch request and save in multithreading. Lock fetched objects?

Tags: objective-c, multithreading, macos, core-data, magicalrecord

I'm using MagicalRecord. After saving some ManagedObject (e.g. "Company") I send notification for reloading Company's TableView immediately and create other object (e.g "People").

Each method "addPeople" execute `[Company findAllWithPredicate:...@"(lastUpdateDate == nil)"]` and generate `arrayOfCompany`.

Then I iterate `arrayOfCompany` with `enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerateConcurrent`.
Each iteration during long time.

As the result during the next intercept notifications and calling "addPerson" returns the same objects of the Company. And in every created thread I'm working with the same objects.

**How lock Company objects during fetchRequest?**

Code example:

**Call first:**

```
+ (void)addCompany
{
    ...
    [arrayOfCompanies enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerateConcurrent
                                      usingBlock:^(Company *obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
    {
        [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
            Company *company = [Company createEntityInContext:localContext];
            ....
        }
        completion:^(BOOL contextDidSave, NSError *error){
            if (contextDidSave)
            {
                [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"newCompanyJustAdded" 
                                                                    object:nil];
            }
        }];
    }];
}
```

**Notification capture:**

```
+ (void)newCompanyJustAdded:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    [Person addPersons];
}

+ (void)addPersons
{
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
        predicate = @"(lastUpdateDate == nil)";
        NSArray *companysInCoreData = [Company findAllWithPredicate:predicate];

        [companysInCoreData enumerateObjectsWithOptions:NSEnumerateConcurrent
                                             usingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
        {
            NSManagedObjectContext *local_context = [NSManagedObjectContext contextForCurrentThread];
            Company *local_company_obj = [obj inContext:local_context];
            ...
            local_company_obj.lastUpdateDate = [NSDate date];
            [local_context saveToPersistentStoreAndWait];
            ...
            ...
            [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)
            {
                Person *person = [Person createEntity];
                person.name = ...
                ...
            });
        }];
    });
}
```

---

**And my second question:**

What is right:

```
[MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)
{
    [someArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock
    {

    }
}];
```

or

```
[someArray enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock
{
    [MagicalRecord saveWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext)

    }
];
```

Answer (score 0):

**For the first question**, don't do either of the options. Instead, use an [`NSFetchedResultsController`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/CoreData/Reference/NSFetchedResultsController_Class/index.html).

**For the second question**, your first option is the correct option. You should open up one context and perform all of your changes and let Magical Record handle saving all of your changes.

If you went with the second option, you'd still be performing the same number of actions, but you would be opening up many contexts.

First option:

```
saveWithBlock: // Called once
enumerateObjectsWithOptions: // Called once
```

Second option

```
saveWithBlock: // Called many times (once for each object)
enumerateObjectsWithOptions: // Called once
```